# Python Pandas: Effectively Paste 1 Col (Series) to Bottom of pd.df w/ >1 Cols; Other Cols of New Rows Should be Empty

Tags: python, pandas

Contrived example:

```
print(testDf)

  col1   col2  col3
0  jim   blue   100
1  bob  green   200
2  joe    red   300

seriesToTackOnToGivenColumn=pd.Series(['yellow','white','black'])
```

[the solution i need]

to get me this:

```
print(testDf)
  col1    col2  col3
0  jim    blue   100
1  bob   green   200
2  joe     red   300
3       yellow   NaN
4        white   NaN
5        black   NaN
```

Disclaimer:
I'm sure the solution to this is simple, but I have researched the solution a good bit and can't find it with the time I have. I'm not afraid of reading the Pandas docs and have done so, but I don't have hours to do so in this case and hence this post. Others will probably benefit if we can get a solution here. Have looked at concat, etc... I'm not interested in the particulars of my example that are incorrect. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help! Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with one column `DataFrame` created by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['yellow','white','black'])

df = pd.concat([df, s.to_frame('col2')], ignore_index=True)
#alternative
#df = df.append(s.to_frame('col2'), ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  col1    col2   col3
0  jim    blue  100.0
1  bob   green  200.0
2  joe     red  300.0
3  NaN  yellow    NaN
4  NaN   white    NaN
5  NaN   black    NaN
```